# How to modify Aged Timeout Property of ConnectionFactory using JMSAdmin of MQ Websphere in Unix

Tags: websphere, connection-pooling

I have a MQXAQueueConnectionFactory created using JMSAdmin of MQ Websphere in Unix. How do I set the Aged Timout properties of the corresponding Connection Pool from commands in Unix?

Appreciate your help a lot.

Thanks in advance.

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fudat_conpoolset.html

==additional info===
I'm using IMB MQ 7.1 on unix